# increase the counter in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

the counter isn't working

mypost is the input value

```
$("#post").click(function() {
    var cont = 0;
    value = $("#mypost").val()
    $("#1").append(value);
    $("#mypost").val('');
    var like = $('<button>like</button>', {
        click: function() {
            cont++;
            $('#1').append(cont);
        }
    });
    $('#1').append(like);
    $('#1').append('</br>');
});​
```

Comment: does anything work? what's `#1`? Do you have an example, or a jsFiddle?

Comment: Instead of saying "isn't working", it is more helpful to tell us *what it does* and *what you expect it to do*.

Comment: I don't think you can have IDs that begin with numbers.

Comment: The `click` handler is the culprit. It never fires.

Comment: @sachleen - in HTML5 you can.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/um3MU/ here is the fiddle

Comment: You're just using the API wrong, but in your defense, jQuery's methods/functions are sometimes overloaded in confusing ways. To pass the second argument, you need to create the element like `$("<button>", your_props)`, and add `text: "like",` to the props. The `jQuery` function is overloaded with far too much behavior, including these ***two*** different ways of creating elements.

Comment: for those interested I found [this article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class) about html5 ids starting with numbers

Answer (score 3):

The event listener isn't properly hooked up when adding it as a property in the `$("<tag />")` constructor. (Despite the [documentation for `$()` mentioning events in the props.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). I believe it's related to the element not being hooked up to the DOM; wild guess.)

Seems to work when adding it on the following line with `.click(function)`.

```
var like = $('<button>like</button>')
    .click(function() {
        cont++;
        $('#1').append(cont);
    });
```

Edit: missed the fact that `#mypost` was read using `.val()`. Updated the jsfiddle to use an `<input />`.

http://jsfiddle.net/joelpurra/bJa29/

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will help but IDs must begin with a letter.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

See [here (http://www.w3.org - Basic HTML data types)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html) for more information.

Comment: Not true.  This restriction is removed in HTML5 and is not enforced by any browser.

Comment: jQuery works without them being a letter. Also, removed in HTML5